# RTX 3090: Unsupported Graphics Card or Driver - OpenGL 3.3 or higher recquired

Tags: error, drivers, opengl

I have 2x RTX 3090 and the drivers up to date, running on windows 10, I also have the latest version of blender.

I get the following error when I try a render or try opening some menus in the application.

> Unsupported graphics card or driver - A graphic card with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is recquired.

I have tried running the program that checks OpenGL version and found out I have OpenGL 4.8 so it can't be that.
I have tried reinstalling blender.
I have tried downloading some OpenGL.dll and put it in the blender folder which was a suggested way I found online but to no success.
I am starting to run out of options, any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a known issue reported at https://developer.blender.org/T85628

Answer (score 2):

It seems to avoid crashing by going to the Nvidia Control Panel, under *Manage 3D Settings* either in the *Global Settings* tab or in the Blender specific *Program Settings*, if you set *OpenGL GPU* to *Auto-Select* to NVidia GeForce RTX #### (2 of 2).

I also had the choice to use "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 (1 of 2)", so I'm wondering if choosing just one will impact performance or if it's normal.

Nothing to report so far though, render went through.

Comment: Nice find, seems to fix the issue on my end as well. Blender used to fail to even launch on my system if my startup layout had two windows on different monitors Also if opening any child window like the file browser the secondary monitor.